# make a field read only in sharepoint list 2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

is there any way to make a field read only (with out programming) in share point          list 2007 which users cannot edit that field can we first build a list and then open in infopath 2007

best regards

Comment: This sounds like 2 different questions. Do you just want a way to make a field read only?  Do you need an InfoPath form, or are you just trying to think of ways to do it?

Comment: Same doubt than Erin L

Comment: I  just want a way to make a field read only